# Puppet: curl call to create vhosts in couchdb

Tags: curl, couchdb, puppet, vhosts

I'm trying to create vhosts for couchDB in a puppet file by using curl:

```
exec {'setup-vhosts':
    command => "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts/mycool.url -d '"/my_database"'",
    require => [Service['couchdb'], Package['curl']],
}
```

But i'm getting this error:
Syntax error at '''; expected '}' at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/couchdb/manifests/init.pp:19

If I execute the command on the machine itself it works perfectly. How can I escape the command correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should escape the double quotes, or use single quotes in the string only.

```
exec {'setup-vhosts':
    command => "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts/mycool.url -d \"/my_database\"",
    require => [Service['couchdb'], Package['curl']],
}
```

OR

```
exec {'setup-vhosts':
    command => "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts/mycool.url -d '/my_database'",
    require => [Service['couchdb'], Package['curl']],
}
```

Also, note that you'l have to prevent this exec from running at each puppetrun.

Comment: With both options I get this as a response {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}

Comment: That would be a CouchDB error, Puppet is working now.
Sorry, I don't know CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

I did fixed it by using the following:

```
exec {'setup-vhosts':
    command => "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts/mycool.url -d \'\"/my_database\"\'",
    require => [Service['couchdb'], Package['curl']],
}
```

Thanks to Ger Apeldoorn who pointed me out to use the correct escaping.